# How to set up Firebase Authentication, where only a user with a custom password can register?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build an app, where a person can only register using the app, if they have a certain password, which they will input in the sign up form, with the rest of their information. I could just make an if statement in the user side, but that would be reckless, since, anyone can view the source code of my react project. So how can I set this up within firebase?

Currently this is the code I am using to register a user

```
const re = await app
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
```

Alternatively, is there a way to let the users register normally, without a secret key, and for them to register they have to be approved by me manually on the console, or some other tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend against trying to implement this on the frontend with hard-coded values.  To do this securely, you will need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) with a backend that will [create the user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) with the correct password.

Comment: What if I dont want to create a separate backend server? Is there no other way to do this, with just firebase, and maybe even firestore?

Comment: There is no other way to do this securely. The database doesn't matter.  You are just dealing with Firebase Authentication APIs here.

Comment: Okay thanks for the quick reply. Is there any leads you would like to give me? I am fairly new to backend stuff. What should I look up on the internet to create a backend server. I am using react

Comment: You have a nearly infinite number of options.  I can't tell you which one you should use.  Many people who use Firebase also use Cloud Functions.

Comment: Okay last question. What if I have a collection in firestore, with custom keys, and basically before calling the register function, I essentially read this collection, (the security rules for this will be read: true, and write: false), and after reading the collection I can check if the values match up. This should be fairly full proof right, because even if someone has the firebase config keys, they cant just open a new project, since I will have restriction on the domains that can access firestore, which will be my domain.

Comment: This sounds like a completely different question - please post it separately.